# How can i convert this SAS code in to SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sas

```
data GC_OUT.ABCD_2;
    set GC_OUT.TEST;
 
    index_first_non_zero = verify(ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD,"0");
    ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD_1 = substr(ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD, index_first_non_zero);
run;
```

Comment: The data step assignment syntax `variable = expression` recoded for SQL is `expression as variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct translation would be something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table GC_OUT.ABCD_2 as 
  select *
       , verify(ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD,"0") as index_first_non_zero
       , substr(ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD,calculated index_first_non_zero) 
         as ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_CD_1
  from GC_OUT.TEST
;
quit;
```

Comment: Hi @Tom,
can you also explain what exactly we are trying to do in this query.
since i've recently started coding i've very limited knowledge of the subject

Comment: That is a different question.  Read what the VERIFY() and SUBSTR() functions do. Basically the combined effect it to remove the leading zeros from a character string.